# HTTP Request Header - What is Avail-Dictionary?

Tags: .net, web-crawler, httprequest

I'm doing some HTTP requests in .Net and after inspecting the HTTP request sent to a website I found a request header I'm unfamiliar with.

After adding this request header to my crawler the response is no longer XHTML and looks like it's been converted to hexidecimal with ChrW(19) and some other symbols.

- I'm guessing this is some sort of encryption that the browser would usually parse?
- Is there a way to decode this in .net?

I've tried looking online but I can't see much about this header.

```
Avail-Dictionary:yB_90cqI,uz0ZIcfN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avil-Dictionary** is used in the request header to show that the browser supports SDCH protocols. If both the server and the client support this protocal then SDCH encoding will be used before any Gzip or Deflate compression.

> **SDCH: Shared Dictionary Compression over HTTP**
>
> **SDCH**
>
> “SDCH” stands for “Shared Dictionary Compression over HTTP”. It is a
>   protocol for compressing URL responses used when the server and the
>   client share a dictionary that can be referred to for
>   compression/encoding and decompression/decoding. The details of the
>   SDCH protocol are specified in the spec (soon to be moved to github)
>   but in brief:
>
> 1. If the client supports SDCH decoding, it advertises “sdch” in the “Accept-Encoding” header.
> 2. If the server could have encoded a response with a dictionary (but didn‘t, because the client didn’t have the dictionary), it includes an
>      advisory “Get-Dictionary: ” header in its response.
> 3. If the client has a dictionary that the server has previously advertised as being usable for encoding a particular requests, it
>      advertises that dictionary as being available via an
>      “Avail-Dictionary: ” header in the request.
> 4. If the server chooses to encode a response with a dictionary, it includes “sdch” in a “Content-Encoding” header, in which case the body
>      will reference the dictionary to be used for decoding (which must be
>      one the client advertised in the original request). Encodings may be
>      chained; often responses are SDCH encoded, and then gzip encoded.
>      Reference

SDCH has lacked a lot of interest by developers previously and as such I could not find any libraries to decompress SDCH in .Net

[Documentation Reference](http://blog.endpoint.com/2009/07/sdch-shared-dictionary-compression-over.html)

[Google Repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/sdch/)